# Query to pair interleaved start and end times

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, report

I need a query to pair interleaved data of 'start' and 'end' times into one neat output, but my main hurdle is with how the data is stored in an interleaved format within the **ProcessTimer** table.

**Input table 1**

I have a table called **ProcessTimer** with three columns.

- **ProcessTimerId** INT (PRIMARY KEY)
- **ProcessTimerDatetime** DATETIME
- **ProcessTimerAction** VARCHAR(5)
- **ProcessId** INT (FOREIGN KEY)

'**ProcessTimerAction**' is only ever set to the value 'START' or 'STOP', which ties in to the '**ProcessTimerDatetime**' column, because '**ProcessTimerDatetime**' stores a DATETIME value of when a Process has started or stopped.

Each Process is identified via a **ProcessId**, and that links to another table called **Process**, which has some details about each Process.

**Input table 2**

The **Process** table is set up as follows:

- **ProcessId** INT (PRIMARY KEY)
- **ProcessName** VARCHAR(255)
- **ProcessOwner** VARCHAR(255)

Logically, a Process's START action should always be followed by a STOP action, and display in pairs, however errors in the data mean that there isn't always a STOP action for every START action. In these instances there's nothing I can do but display a NULL for the missing STOP entry

**Desired output**

I wish to represent the data in grid with the following headings.

- **ProcessOwner**
- **ProcessName**
- **ProcessStartTime**
- **ProcessEndTime**

Has anyone achieved something like this before?

I'm unsure how to begin to tackle creating the query I need.

**Example data**

**ProcessTimer** table

```
ProcessTimerId,ProcessTimerDatetime,ProcessTimerAction,ProcessId
1,1/1/2017 08:00:34,START,883
2,1/1/2017 08:03:76,STOP,883
3,1/1/2017 08:03:77,START,445
4,1/1/2017 08:03:79,START,636
5,1/1/2017 08:05:77,STOP,445
6,1/1/2017 08:07:34,START,445
7,1/1/2017 08:09:23,START,445
8,1/1/2017 08:12:61,STOP,636
9,1/1/2017 08:14:65,STOP,445
```

**Process** table

```
ProcessId,ProcessName,ProcessOwner
445,CTC hourlies,Sarah Parkes
636,Garage import,John Dean
883,DF task,Kate Duke
```

Comment: Are you talking about getting the Start and Stop time on one row?

Comment: If so At a Row_Number Partitioned by ProcessId. Join onto it's self with the RID = RID + 1 AND ProcessId = ProcessId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one implementation:

```
WITH ProcessTimerWithRowNum([ProcessId], [ProcessTimerAction], [ProcessTimerDatetime],[rno])
AS
( SELECT [ProcessId],
         [ProcessTimerAction],
         [ProcessTimerDatetime], 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProcessId ORDER BY ProcessTimerId) AS [rno] 
  FROM  ProcessTime )

SELECT PT.[ProcessId], 
       P.[ProcessOwner], 
       P.[ProcessName], 
       PT.[ProcessTimerDatetime] AS StartTime, 
       DPT.ProcessTimerDatetime AS EndTime FROM

ProcessTimerWithRowNum PT 

LEFT JOIN

ProcessTimerWithRowNum DPT

ON PT.ProcessId = DPT.ProcessId  AND DPT.ProcessTimerAction = 'STOP' AND DPT.rno = PT.rno + 1

INNER JOIN Process P ON PT.ProcessId = P.ProcessId

WHERE PT.ProcessTimerAction = 'START'
```

Output for above data:

```
ProcessOwner | ProcessName | StartTime | EndTime  

445 |Sarah Parkes|  CTC hourlies|   1/1/2017 08:03:77|  1/1/2017 08:05:77

445 |Sarah Parkes|  CTC hourlies|   1/1/2017 08:07:34|  NULL

445 |Sarah Parkes|  CTC hourlies|   1/1/2017 08:09:23|  1/1/2017 08:14:65

636 |John Dean| Garage import|  1/1/2017 08:03:79|  1/1/2017 08:12:61

883 |Kate Duke| DF task|    1/1/2017 08:00:34|  1/1/2017 08:03:76
```

Comment: The only change I had to make was `OVER(PARTITION BY ProcessId ORDER BY ProcessTimerId) AS [rno] ` to `OVER(PARTITION BY ProcessId ORDER BY ProcessTimerDateTime) AS [rno] `. I think this is because sometimes the times can enter the database out of sequence. Does that sound right to you? I currently have my L plates on with understanding this query.