# Pivot temp table without aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

```
          Date            Time         Mode ID

         2017-01-01   13:00:00.0000000  3   10

         2017-01-01   14:00:00.0000000  1   10

         2017-01-01   15:00:00.0000000  3   10

         2017-01-01   15:30:00.0000000  1   10
```

This is a temp table.I want to pair these data.I just want the below output:

```
                 InTime(Mode-3)     OutTime(Mode-1)   

                 13:00:00.0000000   14:00:00.0000000    

                 15:00:00.0000000   15:30:00.0000000
```

I need to get the In Out timings in same row as above

Comment: We need more information than what you provided to generate an answer here.  How is the ordering and partitioning be determined which results in your expected output?  All dates and ID are the same, and the mode appear to be getting ignored.

Comment: Is this similar to what you want? [Query to pair interleaved start and end times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42364642/query-to-pair-interleaved-start-and-end-times/42366042#42366042)

Comment: First is a temp table for the same userID-10 and time is shown as mode 3 means ,punch out time and mode 1 means punch in time.I just want to pair these data.for punch in time and punch out time
          InTime(Mode-3)    OutTime(Mode-1)     

        13:00:00.0000000  14:00:00.0000000    

         15:00:00.0000000  15:30:00.0000000

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pivot temp table in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42486431/how-to-pivot-temp-table-in-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated to to Question Update:**
This works, depending on the data and datatypes/schema (and if the name of the table is ***timeTable***):

```
    SELECT time AS 'InTime(Mode-3)',
      (SELECT TOP 1 time FROM timeTable
          WHERE mode = 1 
            AND id = outerTable.id 
            AND date = outerTable.date 
            AND time > outerTable.time 
          ORDER BY date, time) AS 'OutTime(Mode-1)' 
    FROM timeTable AS outerTable 
    WHERE mode = 3
```

> - the outerQuery only selects the in-times **mode = 3**
> - in innerQuery selects the next out-time, that correspondes to the selected in-time, and only returns the first one. since ordered by date and time, it should be the next one. *Only tested with your given data*

**Output:**

```
         InTime(Mode-3)      |     OutTime(Mode-1) 
  ---------------------------|---------------------------
       13:00:00.0000000      |    14:00:00.0000000
       15:00:00.0000000      |    15:30:00.0000000
```

***Just for reference:***
I used this table schema

```
 CREATE TABLE timeTable(
     date DATE,
     time TIME,
     mode INTEGER,
     id INTEGER
 );
```

Comment: Awesome ! Worked for me Thanks